# How do I code requirements for a registry and login in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, registry

Currently I can log in and register with blank data. I'm not sure how to code a registration "@" symbol that must be present. I'm using Angular.

```
 <form class="form">
     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="">Username</label>
         <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control rounded-0"  required >
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <label>Passwort</label>
         <input [(ngModel)]="registerUserData.password" name="password"  type="password" class="form-control rounded-0" required>
    </div>
    <button (click)="registerUser()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" routerLink="/special">Register</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple articles and videos you can follow to perform registration and login in your app. Some of them are

- [angular 6 user registeration and login](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/05/16/angular-6-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial)
- [user registration in mean stack using angular 6](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-registration-login-example)